# Two views, on top of each other, cross fade between - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I've come across this problem many times before and can't seem to come up with a nice solutions.

I've need to have 2 views (Could be more than 2 views) within a small section of a view controller, both displaying in the same place. I need to switch between these 2 views (Cross fade) on the tap of a button. Both of these views have buttons within them which need to link to an IBAction in the view controller they are being displayed in (Which I thought ruled out the possibility of having separate view controllers for each view).

Are there any simple or elegant solutions to this, without clogging up the storyboard / nib file with views that can't be seen? I'm curious to see how different people approach this problem.

Cheers,
Dave.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem purely involves UI animation, so it shouldn't be solved by adding a new view controller. The following piece of code should help:

```
-(void)buttonTapped {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
         // self.view1 and self.view2 are views that need to be switching
         self.view1.alpha = 0;
         self.view2.alpha = 1;
    }];
}
```

Comment: I don't like how this works in the Nib or the Storyboard. There would be multiple View's on the same spot meaning if you want to edit one view you have to bring it forward in the layering or move it somewhere else in the nib, then move it back.

Comment: I think you have a tree or something of all the views on the left of the Interface Builder (not sure since I don't use IB often). If you're not comfortable with that, just put `view2` anywhere on the screen, and reposition it in the `viewWillAppear` with something like this: `self.view2.frame = self.view1.frame;`

Comment: Yeah, I've done it this way before, this was still has a bit of clutter but is light on the code side to make it work. I was hoping to find a way which is light on the code and doesn't clutter the storyboard too much. I guess I'm asking for too much :-). Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. UI is always cluttered, sometimes it's better to leave it working and focus on sth else :)

Answer (score 1):

The views that you want to animate could be created in code, which would not "clog the storyboard." But then you don't get to visually design that particular view. I'm not fond of that, personally.

One thing I've done in the past is design the non-visible-by-default views as standalone pieces in the nib. (Drag a view onto the design surface, make it free form, then design it as necessary.) You can hook them up to action methods and set outlets with them, just like regular subviews in the main view.

Then in the button action method that handles the view transition, set the frame on the hidden view to the frame of the currently visible one. You can animate as necessary.

This method allows me to design visually, but doesn't clutter up the main view with a bunch of hidden views. It's only cost is the bit of frame and transition code. This might be something that works for you.

Comment: This is also something I've done in the past, and it is a better solution than anything I've done before, but it seems that you can't add standalone views to the storyboard file (I've just started using storyboards!) which is pretty annoying!